# Constructing a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, computational-mathematics

I'm looking for constructive ways to obtain finite fields, for any given size $q=p^n$. For example, I know it suffices to find an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (and then obtain the field as its quotient ring), but how can such polynomial be efficiently found?

Also, I know there are more ways to represent elements of finite fields - are they easier to use than the irreducible polynomial method? What is done in practice in computational mathematical libraries?

Comment: Regarding the last question, I think in practice libraries store explicit irreducible polynomials in a range of practical interest ($p = 2$ and $n = $...?). Regarding the first, perhaps one can try applying Cantor-Zassenhaus to $x^q - x$? What sizes of $p$ and $n$ are you interested in? If $n$ is small compared to $p$ perhaps you can get away with writing down a random polynomial and using some efficient primality tests...

Comment: I think that the best way of representing elements of finite fields depends on what type of operations you want to perform with them. If you do a lot of Frobenius automorphisms (read: squaring in a field of char 2), then an *optimal normal basis* might be best. If your field is relatively small, then you may want to store the entire field as a table. Using either a logarithm table or a Zech logarithm table will convert field arithmetic to integer arithmetic.

Comment: Sage has a decent implementation of finite fields see [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/rings/finite_rings/constructor.html?highlight=finite%20field).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In practice, one guesses an $n$'th degree polynomial and tests it for irreducibility.  As a random polynomial has about a $1/n$ probability of being irreducible, this does not take too long.  For variations and improvements on this idea see this [paper](http://www.shoup.net/papers/fastirred.pdf) by Shoup (author of the [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) library, which you may also want to look at.)